# How to send a json list to post request using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am a newbie to the angular here i am facing an issue below is my jsonlist

```
{Id: 1, Name: "A", Status: false, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1}
{Id: 2, Name: "B", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1}
{Id: 3, Name: "C", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1}
{Id: 5, Name: "D", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1, …}
{Id: 5, Name: "E", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1, …}
{Id: 6, Name: "F", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1, …}
{Id: 7, Name: "G", Status: true, CustTrack: false, RoleId: 1, …}
```

i want to send the above Json List to the server by using the post request and below is my post request format

```
{
  "LocationId": 0,
  "StaffId": 0,
  "CardDetails": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "Name": "string",
      "Status": true,
      "CustTrack": true,
      "RoleId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i achieve this

Json Format
    [{"Id":1,"Name":"A","Status":false,"CustTrack":false,"RoleId":1,"LocationId":2,"CurrentStatus":false},{"Id":2,"Name":"B","Status":true,"CustTrack":false,"RoleId":1,"LocationId":2,"CurrentStatus":false},{"Id":3,"Name":"C","Status":true,"CustTrack":false,"RoleId":1,"LocationId":2,"CurrentStatus":false},]

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Maybe start by reading [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe iwant to send the json list to the server by using post request

Comment: What's the problem in sending that JSON array?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya i dont the process exactly how to send it for single data means by using id i can do it but for list mean i dont know

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem? The data you show doesn't seem to correspond to the format, and we've no idea what the API you're trying to talk to looks like, so how could anyone possibly help you?

Comment: I assume that CardDetails is the array that you've added in the first code snippet, right?

Comment: @jonrsharpe just an idea i have showed the data which i am going to send to server and in which format i need to send to server also all i need is how to process the arraylist in json so that i can send it

Comment: @NiralMunjariya YEAH

Comment: @Madpop Can you add the exact format of the array that you want to send because the list you've mentioned is not the JSON array. It should be like [Object, Object].

Comment: The answer to the general question of how to send a POST  is in the docs, do delete this and read those. If you have a specific question about sending specific data to a specific endpoint, [edit] to give a [mcve], showing; your attempt to make the request; the response; and details of the endpoint interface.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya please check now i updated the format

Comment: I assume that you know the basics of HttpClient in Angular. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object to send:

```
let array = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "A",
  "Status": false,
  "CustTrack": false,
  "RoleId": 1,
  "LocationId": 2,
  "CurrentStatus": false
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "B",
  "Status": true,
  "CustTrack": false,
  "RoleId": 1,
  "LocationId": 2,
  "CurrentStatus": false
}, {
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "C",
  "Status": true,
  "CustTrack": false,
  "RoleId": 1,
  "LocationId": 2,
  "CurrentStatus": false
}];
let jsonToSend = {
  "LocationId": 0,
  "StaffId": 0,
  "CardDetails": array
}
```

HTTP request:

```
this.http.post('url', jsonToSend)
  .subscribe(reponse => {
    console.log('response from the server', response);
  }, err => {
    console.error('Error occurred while sending request', err);
  });
```

Comment: im getting the array list like this  getSelectedRecords(fromTable: any[]){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(fromTable));
  
  }
  }

Comment: Please add the working code snippet. I am not able to get what's the problem that you're facing.

Comment: actually i m working on a table which pushes the data it is some issue can u look over into it?

Comment: What's the issue?